# Automate the Boring Stuff: Phone and Email Address Extractor Error

Tags: python

I copied the code from the Udemy course video yet whenever I run it I get a unbalanced parenthesis error, I tried rewriting it all from the start to make sure I haven't missed anything but I still get the same error.

```
import re, pyperclip


# Create a regex for phone numbers
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''
# 415-555-000, 555-0000, (415) 555-0000, 555-0000 ext 12345, ext. 12345, x12345
(
((\d\d\d)|(\(\d\d\d\)))?          #area code (optional)
(\s|-)# first separator
\d\d\d          # first 3 digits
-             # separator
\d\d\d\d            # last 4 digits
((ext(\.)?\s)|x)           # extension word-part (optional)
(\d{2,5}))? # extension number-part (optional)
)



''', re.VERBOSE)

# TODO: Create a regex for email addresses
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''
#some.+_thing@(\d{2,5}))?.com

[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+          # name part
@          # @ symbol
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+          # domain name part 

''', re.VERBOSE)

# TODO: Get the text off the clipboard
text = pyperclip.paste()

# TODO: Extract the email/phone from this text
extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall(text)
extractedEmail = emailRegex.findall(text)

allPhoneNumbers = []
for phoneNumber in extractedPhone:
    allPhoneNumbers.append(phoneNumber[0])

print(extractedPhone)
print(extractedEmail)

# TODO: Copy the extracted email/phone to the clipboard
```

Error Message:

````
  File "C:\Users\alish\MyPythonScripts\phoneAndEmail.py", line 21, in <module>
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
  File "C:\Users\alish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 234, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\alish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\alish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\alish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py", line 938, in parse
    raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 384 (line 11, column 1)```
````

Comment: Can you copy the error message at least?

Comment: Copied it to the original post.

Comment: `(\d{2,5}))? # extension number-part (optional)`
This hurts my soul to look at but the line above seems to be missing an open parenthesis. Fallout 4 hacking anyone?

Comment: I think you should remove comments in your regex definitions

Comment: Can't believe I failed to see that, thank you mfortes.

Answer (score 0):

An opening parenthesis is missing from line: 
`(\d{2,5}))? # extension number-part (optional)`

Comment: Or is it a closing parenthesis too much? ;)